# In Rails 3 how do I make a config yaml file reloadable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, yaml

I'm in the process of upgrading a Rails app from 2.3.14 to 3.0.5 (intermediate step on the way to 3.1 then 3.2).

There is a language translation system already built in the existing app. Eventually we may migrate it to use ruby/rails I18n, but not today.

The translation system has an initializer defined in .../app/config/initializer. The initializer loads a yaml file that lives at .../app/config/messages.yml and massages it into a new hash keyed on the path to the template(s) where the message is referenced.

As it happens, ApplicationController::Base.template does not work in Rails 3, so, now I'm reworking the messages.yml file so that messages are keyed on the controller#action. It is a tedious process of changing template path to controller#action page by page. It would be less tedious if I did not have to restart the server after every change.

Is there a way I can make Rails rerun the initializer when .../app/config/message.yml has changed?